# JDBC Select Query with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a connection with MySQL database like this

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("Select name, id FROM club WHERE ? > 0")
preparedStatement.setString(1, obj.getVisit);
```

I am getting the error `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'visit' > 0 ' at line 1.`

How do I passed in dynamic column name for this?

**EDIT* I have 4 different column names for this hence I needed it to be dynamic.**

Comment: Formatting your question will increase the visibility and it will make the question more understandable. You can make use of various markdown syntax to format your code and errors. [Visit Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for more details on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to dynamically populate query string.

```
String query = "Select name, id FROM club WHERE "+ columnNamee + " > 0";
```

The reson to this in the first place to prevent SQL injection, so that any  string parameter value is quoted by default.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build statement as a string?

```
String column = obj.getVisit()// get column you want to query 
String query = String.format("Select name, id FROM club WHERE %s > 0", column);
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query)
```